# How to use startWith method in RxJava while using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

Im trying to pass loading , success and error status while using `Retrofit` with `RxJava` . My output is wrapped by `Response` from `Retrofit` package and would like to use `startWith` method from `RxJava` in order to pass `loading` status from `Resource` class . When I add `startWith` the code does not work and has syntax error .

Retrofit interface :

```
@POST
@FormUrlEncoded
Flowable<Response<ResponseMobileGetAccess>> getAccess(@Url String url, @FieldMap HashMap<String, Object> requestModel);
```

The place where I execute this method with RxJava :

```
 public Flowable<Resource<ResponseMobileGetAccess>> registerMobile(
        @NonNull String username) {

    HashMap<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
    body.put("param1", ACTION_MOBILE_GET_ACCESS);

    return Flowable
            .defer(() -> localAccountMobileApiService.getAccess(ACTION_MOBILE_GET_ACCESS, body)
            .map(response -> {
                if (responseMobileGetAccessResponse.isSuccessful()) {
                    return Resource.success(responseMobileGetAccessResponse.body());
                } else {
                    return Resource.error();
                }
            })).startWith(Resource.loading());
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ive just changed these codes to :

```
 public Flowable<Resource<ResponseMobileGetAccess>> registerMobile(
        @NonNull String username) {

    HashMap<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
    body.put("param1", ACTION_MOBILE_GET_ACCESS);

    Flowable<Resource<ResponseMobileGetAccess>> defer = Flowable
            .defer(() -> localAccountMobileApiService.getAccess(ACCOUNT_MOBILE_URL, body)
                    .map(response -> {

                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            ResponseMobileGetAccess data = response.body();

                            if (data != null) {

                                if (data.getStatusCode() > 0) {
                                    return Resource.success(data);
                                } else {
                                    return Resource.serverFailed(data.getStatusText());
                                }

                            } else {
                                return Resource.httpFailed();
                            }

                        } else {
                            return Resource.httpFailed();
                        }

                    }));

    return defer.startWith(Resource.loading());
}
```

Although Im not sure this is a standard way , it works .